# Regex that validates there is space after a period in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following strings:

- I am happy.And I know it.
- I am happy. And I know it.
- I am happy.
- I am happy

The rule is simple: There must be a space after the period. Only one of these should fail, I have tried:

- `new RegExp(/(\.\s|^)(?!\S)/)`

The result is:

```
new RegExp(/(\.\s|^)(?!\S)/).test('I am happy.And I know it.')
false


new RegExp(/(\.\s|^)(?!\S)/).test('I am happy. And I know it.')
false


new RegExp(/(\.\s|^)(?!\S)/).test('I am happy.')
false


new RegExp(/(\.\s|^)(?!\S)/).test('I am happy')
false
```

Only the first one should fail. The rest should pass.

I think I am close, I just need to adjust it to say "Do we have a character/word anything after the period, if so - require a space"

Thoughts?

Comment: The OP should come up with a negated form of the regex ... something like this [`/\.(?!\s)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/0vbEa7/1) or that [`/\.[^\s]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/0vbEa7/2) or as simple as [`/\.\S/g`](https://regex101.com/r/0vbEa7/3) and then [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) it as negated result ... `!(/\.(?!\s)/g).test(sampleData)` or `!(/\.[^\s]/g).test(sampleData)` or `!(/\.\S/g).test(sampleData)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assert that there is not a dot present followed by a non whitespace character.

```
^(?!.*?\.\S)
```

See the matched positions at the [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/G9gOZ4/1).

```js
console.log(/^(?!.*?\.\S)/.test('I am happy.And I know it.'));
console.log(/^(?!.*?\.\S)/.test('I am happy. And I know it.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

just test for . followed by a word and negate

```
!(/\.\w/.test('I am happy.And I know it.'))
```

or . followed by non-whitespace and negate

```
!(/\.\S/.test('I am happy.And I know it.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider testing for periods without spaces after them using the regex `\.[^ ]` e.g.

```
str = "I am happy."
!str.search(/\.[^ ]/)
true
```